# FindPeaks in a 2d list and half values

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, interpolation, peak-detection

`FindPeaks` is a nice little help. But it only works on 1D lists and tends to return half integer values for positions of the peaks which are ultimately very useless for 2D lists. Take for example:

```
values = {1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1};
xpos = RandomReal[1, 16] // Sort;
data = Transpose@{xpos, values};
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

Then `FindPeaks` produces:

```
peaks = FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]]
(* {{9/2, 6}, {10, 7}, {13, 4}} *)
```

And what now? How do I translate this to the x-axis values of the `data`? Is there another function that will do just that?

Comment: `FindPeaks` only supports regularly spaced 2D (time series) data. Would you be interested in solution(s) using WFR entries or paclets?

Comment: You could create an interpolation (e.g. `ListInterpolation`) of your `xpos` which you can use to map your peak locations to your xpos domain.

Comment: `Pick[xpos, PeakDetect@values, 1]`

Comment: @Alan Works, if OP _really_ means "2D lists", not "time series." If time time series are the target, then resampling to regular spaced time series can be applied.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Just to clarify, these are measurements from an instrument at more or less equal intervals. However, I do not want to work with timeseries as they are abysmally slow (not sure why but what takes 20 minutes for a time series object takes a few seconds for interpolating function), possibly a memory issue. Anyway, the goal is to have touples - {xpos, peak_value}. Additionally, I am not sure what WFR entry is or what paclets are in Mathematica. At this point I lean towards interpolation lericr suggested but I hoped to avoid that with some more elegant solution.

Comment: @atapaka WFR = [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/). WL "paclets" are WL packages -- see [Wolfram Language Paclet Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/).

Comment: @atapaka It might be helpful if you post data that resembles the data you deal with in size and shape.

Comment: @AntonAntonov you can get a smaller dataset I am working with by CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/fe7bc44d-bb27-4049-93cc-7532cf449ae5"]

Comment: @atapaka There seem to be both correctness- and permission issues with the link you posted.

Comment: @AntonAntonov i have hopefully corrected the permissions issue: `CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/fe7bc44d-bb27-4049-93cc-7532cf449ae5"]`

Comment: @atapaka Yes, that new links/get works.

Answer (score 5):

```
values = {1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1};
xpos = BlockRandom[RandomReal[1, 16] // Sort, RandomSeeding -> 3]
data = Transpose@{xpos, values};
tops = Pick[data, PeakDetect@values, 1]
ListLinePlot[data, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[tops]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @atapaka - Or to use `FindPeaks`, use `tops = data[[FindPeaks[values][[All, 1]] /.
    r_Rational :> (Sequence @@ {Floor[r], Ceiling[r]})]]`